# redirect issue in codeigniter when using if statement

Tags: codeigniter

i have been trying to redirect the same previous page after delete or inserting the data using if condition in the controller to flash the message but there is something i am missing.

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>curdler/add/tbl_category/addCat/category" method="post">
Category Title<input type="text" name="category_title"/> </br>
<input type ="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
```

Controller

```
public function add() {

    $data = $_POST;
    $tableName = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $content = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $folderName = $this->uri->segment(5);

    $this->load->model('curdmodel');

    if($this->curdmodel->add($data, $tableName)){

    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Category added');
    redirect('welcome/index/'.$content.'/'.$folderName);
    } else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Category Not Added');
    }
}
```

when using the if statement it goes to the different url but without if statement its working fine.

model

```
    public function add($data, $tableName) {
    $this->db->insert($tableName, $data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your redirect only occurs if the if statement evaluates to be true, if the condition is false codeigniter is just setting the flashdata and then ending the script.

Consider changing the order of your code to something like

```
if($this->curdmodel->add($data, $tableName)){
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Category added');
} else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Category Not Added');
}
redirect('welcome/index/'.$content.'/'.$folderName);
```

Additionally, your model does not contain any return value and therefore will never pass data back for the if statement to be evaluated. You should update your model as follows:

```
public function add($data, $tableName) {
    $this->db->insert($tableName, $data);
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: something i am not understanding. the upper function for model is working perfectly fine and data are being stored into the database but the session always flash the else message "CATEGORY NOT ADDED".

Comment: @umanga I've updated my answer, there's also something missing from your model that I didn't spot before.